# Tuleap installation issue on RHEL7.1

Tags: installation, tuleap

I am following [the installation guide](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html#installation) to install Tuleap on RHEL7.1.  When I run this command:

```
yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras tuleap-all
```

I get the following errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 3:mailman-tuleap-2.1.12-18.2.el6.x86_64 (Tuleap)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: tuleap-8.0.99.51-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: perl-suidperl
Error: Package: gitolite-2.3.1-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
Error: Package: tuleap-all-8.0.99.51-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: mysql-server
Error: Package: 3:mailman-tuleap-2.1.12-18.2.el6.x86_64 (Tuleap)
           Requires: vixie-cron >= 4.1-9
Error: Package: tuleap-8.0.99.51-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: vixie-cron >= 4.1-9
Error: Package: tuleap-8.0.99.51-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
           Requires: mod_auth_mysql
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL 7.1 is not supported up to this point. You should try your installation on an RHEL 6 platform.

[Tuleap documentation](https://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html#requirements)

Comment: It's generally good practice to cite a reference for information like this.  Otherwise, the answer could be perceived as opinion or potentially that you are misinformed.  (Also, documented posts tend to get upvoted more.)

Comment: https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=8036